# Attempting to Databind an ObservableCollection to a ListView the MVVM Way

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, data-binding

I'm new to WPF/MVVM and have been attempting to bind an observable collection class to a list view, no code behind, just MVVM.

The XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:acLengthCalcVM/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Header="Section(s) Selected" Margin="3,10,3,10">
        <ListView x:Name="lvSections" Margin="0,6,0,2" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding SectionsSelected}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="30"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Reference Tag #" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Section Type" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Section Length" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The View Model:

```
Public Class acLengthCalcVM
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Dim _sectionsSelected As ObservableCollection(Of acLengthCalcModel) = New ObservableCollection(Of acLengthCalcModel)
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


Public Property SectionsSelected As ObservableCollection(Of acLengthCalcModel)
    Get
        Return _sectionsSelected
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of acLengthCalcModel))
        _sectionsSelected = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SectionsSelected")
    End Set
End Property


Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

End Class

The Model:

```vb
Public Class acLengthCalcModel
Inherits ObservableCollection(Of acLengthCalcData)
Public Sub New()
    Add(New acLengthCalcData(1, "n/a", "VTU Frame", 8))
    Add(New acLengthCalcData(2, "1.1.01", "Air Conveyor Straight", 118))
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class acLengthCalcData
' Constructor for this Class
Public Sub New(serialNum As Integer, refTagNum As String, sectionType As String, sectionLength As Double)
    _refTagNum = refTagNum
    _sectionLength = sectionLength
    _sectionType = sectionType
    _serialNum = serialNum
End Sub

' Reference Tag #
Private _refTagNum As String
Public Property RefTagNum As String
    Get
        Return _refTagNum
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _refTagNum = value
    End Set
End Property

' Section Length
Private _sectionLength As Double
Public Property SectionLength As Double
    Get
        Return _sectionLength
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        _sectionLength = value
    End Set
End Property

' Section Type
Private _sectionType As String
Public Property SectionType As String
    Get
        Return _sectionType
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _sectionType = value
    End Set
End Property

' Serial #
Private _serialNum As Integer
Public Property SerialNum As Integer
    Get
        Return _serialNum
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _serialNum = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

When I run the code, the list view is created with only its headers, none of the data I initialized in the model constructor shows up.

[image]

Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Observable collections should be read only properties. They have change notification. You can use tools like Snoop to examine your bindings at runtime, might give you a hint as to why they aren't working.

Comment: Thanks Will. D'you think maybe if I used an ordinary list instead? The items I need to display do not require any change notification; simply a display of a bunch of items under those headings?

Comment: There is more than one problem here...otherwise I would fix it.  (1) Empty sections selection collection constructed...thus list should be empty.  (2) ListView bound to a collection of a collection...cannot possibility be what you wanted.  (3) GridViewColumn needs a DisplayMemberBinding...and so on.  So get it a little closer and we will fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Cutting it down now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create and return an instance of a `acLengthCalcModel` in your view model class:

```
Public Class acLengthCalcVM
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Dim _sectionsSelected = New acLengthCalcModel
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


    Public Property SectionsSelected As acLengthCalcModel
        Get
            Return _sectionsSelected
        End Get
        Set(value As acLengthCalcModel)
            _sectionsSelected = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SectionsSelected")
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

You also need to bind each of the columns to a property of the `acLengthCalcData` class using the `DisplayMemberBinding` property:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvSections" Margin="0,6,0,2" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding SectionsSelected}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SerialNum}" Width="30"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Reference Tag #" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RefTagNum}" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Section Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SectionType}" Width="150"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Section Length" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SectionLength}" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! To create and return an instance of a acLengthCalcModel in my view model class; that, and implementing DisplayMemberBinding on the GridViewColumns in the XAML. Purr-fect!